# aws security groups: allow ec2 instance to access its own ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, aws-security-group

I want all members of security group `sg-a` to be able to access several ports, e.g. 6443 (kubernetes api server), on all instances in `sg-a`: including themselves.

I create a rule in `sg-a` that says

- Type: Custom TCP
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 6443
- Source: `sg-a`

However, `instanceA` cannot access port 6443 on itself.

When I update "Source" to Source: `instanceA.public.ip.address` , then `instanceA` can access port 6443 on itself.

However, I now have instance specific rules in my security group. If possible, I would like to find a solution where I do not have to add new rules when I add a new instance to my security group

Comment: Are these nodes not connecting to each other by private IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the security group to operate as you describe, the instances will need to connect to each other via a **Private IP address**.

The fact that it works if you allow the Public IP address indicates that the connection is being made by the public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue; adding an inbound-rule with the following setup fixed it for me

- Type: Custom TCP
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 6443
- Source: Custom
- IP: 0.0.0.0/32

I am by no means an expert on networking so it could be that what I added is not the optimal configuration but at least I was able to connect properly